# Add filter in request. ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have my request:

```
*{

"query": {
"range": {
"@timestamp": {
"gt": "now-8h"
}
}
},

"filter" :{
"term": {
"user-id": "661474"
} 
},

"sort": [
{
"@timestamp": {
"order": "asc"
}
}
]
}*
```

and I want to add filter for display only document with strings "log out" and "log in" in "message" field.
But i can't understand where i have to put this filter in my request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to set these values as a filter and not a query, the following filter would function.

This will combine your existing filter of a numeric value on the userid field with a terms filter on the message field, the bool and must keywords signifying that both filters must evaluate to true to be returned.

You should read the docs on [combining](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/combining-filters.html) filters and the [terms](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-filter.html) filter to understand how it functions.

```
"filter": {
            "bool" : {
                "must" : [
                    {"term" : { "user-id" : "661474" } },
                    {"terms" : { "message" : ["log out", "log in"] } },
                ]
             }
         }
```

Edit to reflect clarification in comments:

```
"query": {
    "query_string": {
      "default_field": "message",
      "query": "log in OR log out"
    }
  }
```

Query string syntax docs can be found [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.3/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#query-string-syntax).

Comment: and if "log out" and "log in" is the part of message(not whole) how I can replace "term"?

Comment: If you are looking to search a string contained in a field which is indexed as a larger string, that would fall under a simple Query String. Edited answer to reflect.